# Arduino and AVR Serial Communication over USB

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, usb, atmega328, avr

I have a Arduino Uno Rev3 and I would like to use a AVR development toolchain to write a program that performs serial communication over USB.

Doing this using the Arduino IDE is fairly simple:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   int i;
   while(1) {
      Serial.write("hello\n");
      delay(5000);
   }
}
```

Then from Linux, I can simply read from `/dev/ttyACM0` and every 5 seconds I get "hello\n".

I found a blog post titled [Simple Serial Communications With AVR libc](https://appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc) that explains how to perform serial communication using an AVR development toolchain. The simplified version of the above Arduino sketch is below.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#endif

#ifndef BAUD
#define BAUD 9600
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

void uart_init() {
    // Upper and lower bytes of the calculated prescaler value for baud.
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

    // Configure data frame size to 8-bits.
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);

    // Configure to enable transmitter.
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0);
}

void uart_putchar(char c) {
    // Wait until the register to write to is free.
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);

    // Write the byte to the register.
    UDR0 = c;
}

void uart_putstr(char *data) {
    // Loop until end of string writing char by char.
    while(*data){
      uart_putchar(*data++);
    }
}

int main() {
    uart_init();

    while(1) {
        uart_putstr("hello\n");
        _delay_ms(5000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, this doesn't actually work. I can build and flash the ATmega328p but reads to `/dev/ttyACM0` block forever. I suspect what is happening is that the serial communication is occurring on some pins and not over USB, but I am not sure.

Anyone have any idea on how I can emulate `Serial.write` using an AVR development toolchain and have the output be written over USB?

Comment: `8000000UL` my Uno board has a standard 16MHz crystal on it. Besides, what program / command do you use for reading out data over `dev/ttyACM0`?

Comment: I tried `16000000UL` as well, still didn't work. I originally switched to `8000000UL` because the on-board LED did not blink correctly with `16000000UL`.

Comment: As for reading `/dev/ttyACM0`, I've written a simple program using the following library: http://github.com/pkg/term. However, I imagine `cat` or `tail -f` would show the same results.

Comment: Why is this being closed as off-topic? The help centre [tells](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that questions about other IDEs, clones/counterfeits/derivatives, and other coding languages for Arduino are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my `Makefile`. `avr-gcc` was missing the `-mmcu=atmega328p` flag. Once I added that and changed `F_CPU` to `16000000UL` everything works.